# How can I use a particular library while compiling?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glib

I am on Ubuntu 13.04 32 platform and I'm trying to compile **"birdie"** from source code. 
I get the following error :

```
/birdie/build/src/main.c:98:46: error: too few arguments to function 'g_option_context_add_main_entries'
In file included from /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:66:0,
             from /home/***/Desktop/birdie/build/src/main.c:20:
/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/goption.h:337:17: note: declared here
```

I have `libglib2.0-dev 2.36.3` installed from repository and `glib-2.38.2` installed from source. They installed in different paths like one is on `/usr/lib` and the other is on `/usr/local/lib`

My question is how can I use one library in place of the older one in different path and disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the arguments passed to the `gcc` during compilation.

By default, all the `default path` directories are searched and if there is a match, then those `libraries` are used. To override the behavior, you can additionally specify the `directories` to be searched before the `default path`.

```
gcc <your-file.c> -o <object-file> -I<additional directory to be searched> -L<linking path>
```

In your case, it should be

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib
```

and then pass the above `CFLAGS` to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to set `CFLAGS` like `CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib make` from terminal or do I have to add it into makefile?

Comment: you will have to edit the `CFLAGS` used in the make file. append these at the last.

Comment: Also if you find the answer useful and you found your answer, then mark it as answered. :)

Comment: :) I ll do accept, I bear you in mind. I am yet struggling to overcome that error

Comment: so it means that the `include/link paths` are still not changed. can you make sure that the paths are not overwritten anywhere else in the `makefile`?

Comment: in makefile there is no CFLAGS. How about using `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig` ?

Comment: well, you can try that. may be set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also to see if that helps. add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`

Comment: error message comes from /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:66:0 , so I must exclude /usr/local ?

Comment: that's the default system search path. you can't change that i think. paste the output of `cpp -v`

Comment: can you run this command `apt-file search /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib.h` and paste the output?

Comment: so the headers being used are coming from the `glib source package` and not from the `libglib2.0-dev_2.36.3` package. can you uninstall the sources and then check..?

Comment: After uninstalling glib that I  compiled from sorce I still get `In file included from /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:66:0,
                 from /home/***/Desktop/birdie/build/src/main.c:20:`
message when I attempt to compile birdie

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50154/discussion-between-dreamer-and-kenn)

Comment: I used instructions in this link beside dreamer's answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488187/pkg-config-modversion-glib-2-0-reports-older-version/488424#488424